# Is it possible to turn off error checking while i am typing in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax, disable

I am programming in C#, using Visual Studio Code. It insists on checking for syntax errors (red squiggles) while I'm typing, instead of just on save. This results in lots of "errors" that wouldn't be there if only it would wait until I'm done typing. I did Google search but found no solution, only other people, a lot of them, complaining at the same issue.

Is there any way to disable error checking while I am typing, or is it something I have to live with.

The suggestions like adding lines in settings.json like
"java.validate.enable": false
"javascript.validate.enable": false
"problems.decorations.enabled": false

do not work for C#.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable error highlighting in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46061857/how-to-disable-error-highlighting-in-vs-code)

Comment: @Mitch, thanks but the suggestions in that post did not work for me, since I am using C#. I've seen that post before and tried the different suggestions but none of them worked for me. They might work for Java or JavaScript, but not for C#.

Comment: Do you have a C# linter that is running `onType` - maybe you have already looked for this?

Comment: I suppose the real question is "why wouldn't you want interactive error checking?"

Comment: @Mitch, I do want error checking, but not while I type. Why should I have red squiggles all over the place, while I am typing perfectly legal code. An analogy. Let say I am writing a letter and I want to write Greetings. I start with G, and somebody behind my back is saying to me "G"is not a word. I continue with r and the person behind me is saying, "Gr" is not a word either. And it continues this way until I have written the whole word Greetings until he finally shuts up. That is not a fun way to write a letter. Not for me anyway.

Comment: @Mark, the only extension I have in Visual Studio is "C# for Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp)". I suspect that this is the one checking for syntax errors. Is that what you mean by C# linter? And I do not understand what you are referring to when you say "onType". What is that?