# Disable error/warning notification only for a particular language

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use `Visual studio code` to write programs in different language like `C++, python` etc.

I want to disable of intimation of different error/warnings notification for a particular language e.g. `python` only not `C++`

One such error/warning notification is `Lines should not be more than 80 characters.line_length_linter`

I want to disable all such notification only for python.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Based on suggestion from @starball, I added following lines in `settings.json` file from [How can I easily toggle display of problem underlining in VS Code editor panels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74753185/how-can-i-easily-toggle-display-of-problem-underlining-in-vs-code-editor-panels)

```
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
      "[Visual Studio Light]": {
        "editorError.foreground": "#00000000"
      },
      "editorError.foreground": "#00ff00"
    }
  }
```

With that, my `settings.json` file looks like below

[image]

But unfortunately, I still dont see any change in the behaviour of my console. Any further help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @starball Thanks for your suggestion. I appended my `settings.json` file based on the suggestion provided in your link, but still dont see any change. I updated my original post with this information

Comment: I don't understand [Dimiva's answer](/a/74916238/11107541), which you tried. Try `"workbench.colorCustomizations": {  "editorError.foreground": "#0000" }`. In any case, colour customizations cannot be made on a per-language-basis, as far as I know.

Comment: I still getting underlying with statements like `Lines should not be more than 80 characters.line_length_linter`