# How to remove or turn off Roslyn Analyzer in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Maybe it's from the recent VS Code update, It suddenly pops up..

it's highlighting some of my non-error codes in a blue line and sometimes it translucent some of my variables that doesn't have an error or what.

It's kinda bothering me now the way it looks, I tried searching in google youtube, but I'm at lost, mostly it's for visual studio.

Comment: something tells me you actually want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76850403/11107541

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `omnisharp.enableRoslynAnalyzers` setting. Or if you want to switch back to using OmniSharp for IntelliSense, set `dotnet.server.useOmnisharp` to `true`.

---

If you want to disable warning/hint diagnostics, you might be able to do it with an editorconfig like this if you have editorconfig support enabled ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/15jnnmi/psa_how_to_disable_roslyn_suggestionsblue/)):

```
[*.{cs,vb}]
dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.category-Style.severity = none
dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.category-CodeQuality.severity = none
```

Or alternatively, if you want to just hide the squiggly underlines, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74934214/11107541.

Comment: Note: due to timing of this question makes me think this is the bug we shipped, and since that's the non-Omnisharp side changing the omnisharp.enableRoslynAnalzyers flag won't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

We had a bug in the 2.0 line of the VS Code extensions where it's showing a lot of blue squiggles when we didn't expect it. This is fixed in 2.0.346 or later.

Comment: link to issue ticket(s) please?

Comment: It appears we never filed a bug -- we just fixed it in 2.0.346. That's a prerelease build that has a different bug around go to definition so we didn't promote it to stable yet but any build 2.0.346 or later should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Following the link from the first comment, you'd need to:

1. Disable Roslyn.
2. Re-Enable Omnisharp as the language server.
3. Disable/remove another extension.

## Roslyn

In settings- search for and disable `Enable Roslyn analysers`.

## OmniSharp

1. In settings- Search `dotnet.server.Use Omnisharp`
2. Enable this setting.
3. Remove (or disable) extension: `C# Dev Kit`
4. Restart!

Note: It seems like some smarty pants decided it would be wise to remove omnisharp, so doing this will prompt it to be re-downloaded.