# Error squiggly lines not displaying in Visual Studio Code using C# even after enabling

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I've read all the available info relating to this question and I still cannot get it to work!

I'm new to VS Code and C#.
I am undertaking this Microsoft training and have followed it exactly and even it says I should be seeing error lines when entering this code.

[image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/csharp-call-methods/3-call-methods

I get nothing, even when I leave off a semi-colon.

[image]

**Things I have tried:**

- Enabling error squiggles in User and Workspace settings and settings.json file.
  What is interesting about this is these options are only on the C/C++ extension but I'm
  using C#. I have tried enabling any option that seems related on the C# extensions but
  there is not a like-for-like option.

[image]

- Uninstalling and reinstalling the extensions and VS Code

Someone spoke of uninstalling and re-installing Intellisense - I couldn't find how to do this - seems built into the extensions?

Other people have pointed to the C# extension instruction:

*Open a folder/workspace that contains a C# project (.csproj) and a C# solution (.sln) and the extension will activate.*

[https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp#:~:text=How%20to%20use%20OmniSharp%3F,for%20this%20to%20take%20effect](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp#:%7E:text=How%20to%20use%20OmniSharp%3F,for%20this%20to%20take%20effect).

I believe I have met that requirement as I have both those files in the folder.

I'm really stumped and it's preventing me from continuing this course as not having error lines is hard enough when you know what you are doing, let alone when you don't.

**System Specs**

These are the extensions that are enabled:

[image]

I'm using Windows 11 on a PC

VS Code 1.86.2

This is my dotnet --info

.NET SDK:
Version:           8.0.201
Commit:            4c2d78f037
Workload version:  8.0.200-manifests.3097af8b

Runtime Environment:
OS Name:     Windows
OS Version:  10.0.22621
OS Platform: Windows
RID:         win-x86
Base Path:   C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\8.0.201\

.NET workloads installed:
There are no installed workloads to display.

Host:
Version:      8.0.2
Architecture: x86
Commit:       1381d5ebd2

.NET SDKs installed:
8.0.201 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.2 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.7 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.2 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.7 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 8.0.2 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

As I am new to this so please explain HOW to do something if you have a suggestion.

Many thanks.

Comment: Check the settings for `Dotnet > Background Analysis: Compiler Diagnostics Scope`, the default should be `openFiles`. Also, open the output window (View > Output) and in the dropdown, check the C# related logs to see if it has obvious errors

Comment: Thank you. I have changed those settings to default - it was not set to that. That has not resolved it, but I do have a suspicious error in the output.

Comment: 'Failed to find dotnet info from path, falling back to acquire runtime via ms-dotnettools.vscode-dotnet-runtime. The architecture of the .NET runtime (x86) does not match the architecture of the extension (x64).'

Should I be installing a different runtime version or is it possible to change it in the extension?

Side note- I purposely installed an x86 dotnet SDK to match the runtime I already had showing in cmd (I tried the 64 first and got errors) maybe I should uninstall it all and make sure everything is 64.

Comment: Yeah, please stay on x64. If you're getting errors there, then we will work through *those* errors.

Comment: did you touch any settings from https://stackoverflow.com/a/74934214/11107541

Comment: Update: I've been playing around with the dotnet install for days and cannot get it switched over to x64. System will only recognise a x86 SDK. As I don't even understand the dotnet environment and its dependencies I'm currently searching elsewhere to get some help with that. Will return here to update if this gets resolved.